# Is it possible to configure GDB so it auto quit on normal program termination?

Tags: gdb

I'm debugging a shell script on OSX with mysterious segfault in the middle. The command in question does not segfault if executed outside of script.

So i need to somehow run all programs in script with GDB attached so i can debug this segfault. Is it possible to configure GDB so it will run the program and quit if program terminated correctly? I have tried the following code:

```
echo file ifconfig > gdbcfg
echo run >> gdbcfg
echo quit >> gdbcfg
gdb -x gdbcfg
```

But this is not working since GDB tries to execute `quit` command before application terminates normally :(. Is it possible to somehow instruct GDB to wait for application normal termination and quit after that?

Maybe my approach is too comples and it's just some GDB flag like "load and run this application, quit if all is ok"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make the process to dump a core file and analyze it later with gdb? I mean ulimit -c unlimited and then (after the core is dumped) gdb ./process core?

Comment: I'm not very good with nix toolchain, so this method is technically hard to me, too many questions. I don't know how to make shell script stop after first segfault (and where are subsequent segfaults after first one). I don't know how to correctly dump core and load it back in GDB. So i think that just preceding each app start in shell script and breaking into GDB will be the easiest solution for me :).

Comment: ulimit -c unlimited will force the crashing process to dump a core file called "core". You can make your script to check for "core" file after each command and to exit if it exist (if [ -f core ]; then exit; fi). Then just run gdb with first parameter the process that crashed, and second parameter - the core filename ("core"). That's all.

Answer (score 1):

> But this is not working since GDB tries to execute quit command before application terminates

No: it's not working because (assuming you pasted your *actual* code) the `gdbcfg` contains a single `quit` after your commands are executed (and no `run`). What you want is:

```
echo file ifconfig > gdbcfg
echo run >> gdbcfg
echo quit >> gdbcfg
gdb -x gdbcfg
```

A more UNIXy way to spell that is:

```
echo >gdbcfg <<EOF
file ifconfig
run
quit
EOF

gdb -x gdbcfg
```

Update:

If the file contents of `gdbcfg` contains all three commands, then your understanding of the problem is *incorrect*: GDB will wait for each command to finish before executing the next one.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo in code sample posted here. Actual file is edited with vi and has all 3 commands :( P.S. За трюк с EOF спасибо, как-то я проглядел такой очевидный способ использования heredoc :)